# Converting Moment.js to Day.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, momentjs, dayjs

I recently started working on a Work Day Schedule project that requires me to use jQuery, HTML and Day.js. This project requires that I display a clock at the top of the page, text areas that can be written in and saved to local storage (this text stays even when page is reloaded) and the color of each time block is based on whether it is past(gray), present (red), or future (green).

I have displayed the clock and figured out how to keep text saved in the text area but I cannot figured out how to keep the time blocks appropriately colored based on what time it is.

This is my javascript. The documentation I found to help was sadly written in moment.js and I'm wondering how I would convert this to Day.js to meet the project requirements.

```
var dateTime = $('#dateTime');
var saveBtn = document.querySelector(".saveBtn");

var currentHour = moment().hour();

function printDateTime() {
    var date = moment().format("dddd, MMM Do YYYY")
    dateTime.text(date);
}

function hourTracker() {
    $('.timeSchedule').each(function () {
        var schedulehHour = $(this).attr("id").split("time")[1];
        console.log("currentHour " + currentHour)
        console.log("schedulehHour " + schedulehHour)

        if (schedulehHour < currentHour) {
            $(this).addClass("past");
        }
        else if (schedulehHour == currentHour) {
            $(this).addClass("present");
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("future");
        }
    })
}

$(".saveBtn").on("click", function () {
    var value = $(this).siblings(".description").val();
    var time = $(this).parent().attr("id");

    localStorage.setItem(time, value);
})

$("#time08 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time08"));
$("#time09 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time09"));
$("#time10 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time10"));
$("#time11 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time11"));
$("#time12 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time12"));
$("#time13 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time13"));
$("#time14 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time14"));
$("#time15 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time15"));
$("#time16 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time16"));
$("#time17 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("time17"));

printDateTime();
hourTracker();
```

I tried writing in moment.js but needs to be in day.js.

Comment: have you tried changing it to dayjs?

Comment: I have tried. Actually most is still viable in day.js. However the portion where the colors need to change based on time does not work in day.js. So the printDateTime and hourTracker functions are what really need to be converted. I cannot figure out how.

Comment: function timeFresh() { 
var reformatDate = dayjs().format('dddd MMM D YYYY');
$('#currentDay').text(reformatDate);

}

Comment: This is my converted printDateTime function but I'm not sure if its correct.

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
moment()
```

to

```
dayjs()
```

and add

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

in HTML File

.......

REF: https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/browser